# Monotouch: how to optimize the performance for manual load the NIB

Tags: xamarin.ios, scrollview

I use the scrollview to display multipage view, which have more than 10 pages. (scrollview.PageEnabled=true)

And every single page in scrollview has about 6 sub-view(named:ABCUI) which every one is loaded from nib :

```
    this.scrollview.DecelerationEnded+= scrollView_DecelerationEnded(...);

    public void LoadSubView(int nPageNo)
    {
       if (this.PageLoaded(nPageNo))
          return;

       for (int i=0;i<6;i++)    
       {
         ABCViewController abcUI=MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("ABCUI", this, null); //XIB file size: 20K

         abcui.SetTitle(...);  
         abcui.SetXXXX(...);
         abcui.frame = ..  pageFrame.X += this.ScrollView.Frame.Width+nPage*...;    

         this.scrollview.addsubview(abcUI.view,...);
       }
    }


    public void scrollView_DecelerationEnded (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nPageNo=(int)Math.Ceiling((this.ScrollView.ContentOffset.X+1)/this.ScrollView.Frame.Width);

        this.LoadSubView(nPageNo +1);
        this.LoadSubView(nPageNo - 1);  
    }

public void Button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.ClearViewsInScrollView();
   this.LoadSubView(1); 
}
```

When the user trigger the button1 click, it will load the first page into scrollview(only 1 page oncetime, but 1 page has 6 sub-view), and when user scroll the scrollview , it will load the next page.

But it will take a long time when load the first page or switch page in scrollview , so the user must waiting:

1. ipad1: about 1000ms
2. iPad2: about 600ms
3. in simulator: 100ms;

how to optimize the performance(reduce to less 300ms/ipad1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good question and excellent timing, since I have been working on something like this the past few days.

Now, I am not sure if this solution will get you < 300ms loading, however in theory it is faster.

(You'll see both "XIB" and "NIB" terms. I am referring to the same thing. After all, a NIB is a "compiled" XIB.)

The key to the whole thing is to prevent loading of each XIB file multiple times. There is no reason for it, since what you (we) basically need from it, are **instances** from the objects in the XIBs, and not the XIBs themselves occupying memory.

Fortunately, the iOS SDK provides the `UINib` class which can do what we want. With this class, we can create multiple instances of the contents of a XIB, without having to load the XIB itself each time, just once in the "beginning".

Here's how to do it:

First, create a UINib object for each XIB file you want.

```
// Loads a NIB file without instantiating its contents.
// Simplified here, but to have access to a NIB for the whole lifecycle of the app,
// create a singleton somewhere.
static UINib abcuiNib = UINib.FromName("ABCUI", NSBundle.MainBundle);
```

Second, after you have loaded the NIB into memory, you can now get the objects from it.

```
abcuiNib.InstantiateWithOwneroptions(this, new NSDictionary());
```

Note the "this" parameter. Since it is a view controller you want to load, the above line should be somewhere early in the object's life cycle, eg in the constructor:

```
public partial class ABCViewController : UIViewController
{

    public ABCViewController()
    {

        // The first parameter is needed to set an owner (File's Owner) for the objects
        // that will be instantiated.
        // The second parameter is for various options. It does not accept null in MonoTouch,
        // but you can just pass an empty NSDictionary.
        // If you have all your outlets correctly set up, the following line is all 
        // that is needed.
        abcuiNib.InstantiateWithOwneroptions(this, new NSDictionary());

    }

    // We don't need the following, as it will load the XIB every time
    //public ABCViewController() : base("ABCUI", null) {}

// view controller implementation

}
```

Mind you, I have not tested the above, as so far I have tested it with various single objects in XIBs. If (and when) I use it with UIViewControllers in XIBs, this is the direction I will move in. I'll also prepare an article with more in-depth findings and info in due time.

Also note that the same "rules" apply, eg. you will still have to release all outlets in the `ViewDidUnload` override.

If after this, you do not find any improvement in performance, I think you will need to redesign your XIBs. Apple suggests it is better to have multiple XIBs with few objects in each one, instead of few XIBs packed with objects.

Useful reading: [Apple docs on NIB management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

Comment: I have look for a long time to find solution for cache nib: static UINib abcuiNib = UINib.FromName("ABCUI", NSBundle.MainBundle); it's a amazing solution. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! I would be interested to hear on your performance results, but also your implementation...!

Comment: Sorry, the testing results seemed unsatisfactory, for one sub-view it takes about 70ms, so 6*2=12 sub-view must take for about 70*12=840ms.     this is log(ipad1):  [Start to invoke: InstantiateWithOwneroptions] 
[Finish invoke: InstantiateWithOwneroptions]  since last invoke: 69 ms        Util.LogTime("Start to invoke: InstantiateWithOwneroptions");
 nib.InstantiateWithOwneroptions(this, new NSDictionary());  Util.LogTime("Finish invoke: InstantiateWithOwneroptions");  (the sub-view contains the flowing control: 3 BUTTON & 10 Lables & 1 Images(but loading the image later)

Comment: By the way: I have uploaded the image above for ref.   I'm trying to make some dish display like the above picture in iPad. In order to display many style layout, so I pre-defined some XIB file with different layout style. (the dish image is load async and after the nib loaded, and size is less than 10KB)

Comment: And another question : When user slip the screen ,it will display the next page.  Which one is better: a) UIPageviewController (in the event: GetNextViewController to load next page) , but I wan't need the page curl effect(just page slip effect), how to disabled it? ,    b)UIScrollView, Now I use this solution ,but I must preload 2 pages(12 dishes) because if only load 1 page when user slip the next page it will be blank screen. and the next question is it needs manual manage the instance when display the next page to unload the pervious page in order to reduce the memory useage. thanks a lot.

Comment: I am now reading the book : iOS Development using MonoTouch Cookbook, thanks for your sharing, I have obtained very much from it.

Comment: Regarding the NIB loading: true, that was a small gain in performance. Regarding the rest: difficult to answer everything here, I suggest you post different questions for each. In short, I think you should work in a manner similar to what the UITableView does with the DequeueReusableCell method. That is, create 2 sets of screens *before* (1 for the visible and one for the previous/next), repositioning everything according to the direction the user scrolls.

Comment: @BlueSky: Good to know my book helped! Cheers!

Comment: Hi, the InstantiateWithOwneroptions method takes about 70ms to execute? is that any advice to optimize? thanks.   I have try to create multiple XIBs with few objects to keep the nib smaller(not in the single xib)

Comment: hi, i redesign my outlet in NIB, remove some controls ,  InstantiateWithOwneroptions reduces to 35ms, it's faster now , thanks for your help.